# Add Item To Array List From Another Intent

Tags: java, android, listview, android-intent, arraylist

I have an app that has an ListView of Book objects.  I click a button that takes me to another activity (AddBook) where I can add another book and pass the information back to the MainActivity.  I can create that original Book object and add it to the ListView, but if I try to add a second Book by clicking the add button (on MainActivity) and going through AddBook again when I am return to MainActivity the first book I added is replaced by the second entry.  I think I need a loop or conditional but I can't figure it out.

I added the if statement on line 94 because the object would automatically be added before I filled in the fields on the AddBook Activity

```
    package com.the93rd.android.bookcatalog;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button mAddBook;
public ArrayList<Book> books;
public ListView listView;
public BookListViewAdapter bookAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Array List of Book objects
    books = new ArrayList<>();

    books.add(new Book("J.K. Rolling", "Harry Potter and The Sorcerers Stone", 8,
            "0439708184", "Yes"));
    books.add(new Book("Eoin Colfer", "The Artic Accident", 5,
            "1423124529", "Yes"));
    books.add(new Book("George S. Clason", "The Richest Man in Babylon", 9,
            "1505339111", "No"));
    books.add(new Book("Khaled Hosseini", "The Kite Runner", 10,
            "159463193X", "Yes"));
    books.add(new Book("Daniel Keyes", "Flowers For Algernon", 8,
            "0156030306", "No"));

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    bookAdapter = new BookListViewAdapter(this, books);

    listView.setAdapter(bookAdapter);


    //Open BookDetails Activity to Display more book information
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            //Get ArrayList element
            Book book = books.get(position);

            //Get fields for current Book element
            String passAuthor = book.getAuthor();
            String passTitle = book.getTitle();
            int passRating = book.getRating();
            String passIsbn = book.getIsbn();
            String passSeries = book.getSeries();

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, book.getAuthor(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            //Pass Extras for Book element to BookDetails Activity
            Intent openDetail = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BookDetails.class);
            openDetail.putExtra("Author", passAuthor);
            openDetail.putExtra("Title", passTitle);
            openDetail.putExtra("Rating", passRating);
            openDetail.putExtra("Isbn", passIsbn);
            openDetail.putExtra("Series", passSeries);
            startActivity(openDetail);
        }
    });

    //Open AddBook Activity
    mAddBook = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_book);
    mAddBook.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent addBook = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddBook.class);
            startActivity(addBook);
        }
    });

    //Get extras from AddBook Activity
    Intent intent = getIntent();

    String addAuthor = intent.getStringExtra("addAuthor");
    String addTitle = intent.getStringExtra("addTitle");
    String addRating = intent.getStringExtra("addRating");
    String addIsbn = intent.getStringExtra("addIsbn");
    String addSeries = intent.getStringExtra("addSeries");

    if(addAuthor != null){

        //Add variables from AddBook activity to new Book object
        books.add(new Book(addAuthor, addTitle, 5, addIsbn, addSeries));
        bookAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use startActivityForResult rather than startActivity, so you can receive the data from AdBook Activity, for example

```
 package com.the93rd.android.bookcatalog;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button mAddBook;
    public ArrayList<Book> books;
    public ListView listView;
    public BookListViewAdapter bookAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Array List of Book objects
        books = new ArrayList<>();

        books.add(new Book("J.K. Rolling", "Harry Potter and The Sorcerers Stone", 8,
                "0439708184", "Yes"));
        books.add(new Book("Eoin Colfer", "The Artic Accident", 5,
                "1423124529", "Yes"));
        books.add(new Book("George S. Clason", "The Richest Man in Babylon", 9,
                "1505339111", "No"));
        books.add(new Book("Khaled Hosseini", "The Kite Runner", 10,
                "159463193X", "Yes"));
        books.add(new Book("Daniel Keyes", "Flowers For Algernon", 8,
                "0156030306", "No"));

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        bookAdapter = new BookListViewAdapter(this, books);

        listView.setAdapter(bookAdapter);


        //Open BookDetails Activity to Display more book information
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                //Get ArrayList element
                Book book = books.get(position);

                //Get fields for current Book element
                String passAuthor = book.getAuthor();
                String passTitle = book.getTitle();
                int passRating = book.getRating();
                String passIsbn = book.getIsbn();
                String passSeries = book.getSeries();

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, book.getAuthor(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                //Pass Extras for Book element to BookDetails Activity
                Intent openDetail = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BookDetails.class);
                openDetail.putExtra("Author", passAuthor);
                openDetail.putExtra("Title", passTitle);
                openDetail.putExtra("Rating", passRating);
                openDetail.putExtra("Isbn", passIsbn);
                openDetail.putExtra("Series", passSeries);
                startActivity(openDetail);
            }
        });

        //Open AddBook Activity
        mAddBook = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_book);
        mAddBook.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent addBook = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddBook.class);
                int requestCode = 1;
                startActivityForResult(addBook, requestCode);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        String addAuthor = data.getStringExtra("addAuthor");
        String addTitle = data.getStringExtra("addTitle");
        String addRating = data.getStringExtra("addRating");
        String addIsbn = data.getStringExtra("addIsbn");
        String addSeries = data.getStringExtra("addSeries");

        if(addAuthor != null){
            //Add variables from AddBook activity to new Book object
            books.add(new Book(addAuthor, addTitle, 5, addIsbn, addSeries));
            bookAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }
}
```

in your adBookActivity, make sure to call `setResult(1, data)` before close the activity.

*change 1 (requestcode) as constant, to make the code more readable

Comment: Thank you I did what you said and got the result I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

I think is the best way you should use sqlite DB. And set List box items from sqlite db table it will run fast your app.

Comment: could you please elaborate?

Comment: First you should save your data to sqlite DB. Then Read DB and load it's data to your app and select ListView data scorce as loaded data's correct columns. Save Data to SQlite : https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html help you.

Comment: And Load Data to List View : http://saigeethamn.blogspot.in/2011/02/listview-of-data-from-sqlitedatabase.html help you. This will make your app more efficiency. and you can save lot of data because it does't depend on your ram.